# Triplicating a number by moving Last digit to First digit

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there any integer positive number which triples in value when its last digit is removed and becomes the first digit? I’ve tried with the first 1000 numbers and Excel but could not find any.
First 10,000 numbers, no single case!

is there a rigorous way of tackling such a problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: The following link provides a solution to a similar problem (**do not click the link until you have made an adequate effort towards solving the problem**):  https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2017/07/23/what-number-doubles-when-its-last-digit-becomes-its-first-digit-sunday-puzzle/. Try to apply the ideas here to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks I’ll keep working on the problem and will post the updates here

Comment: The answer is the third term in [A092697](https://oeis.org/A092697).

Comment: For a multiplier of 2, you need 18 digits, $105263157894736842$.  For 3, you need 28 digits as given in an answer below.  But for a multiplier of 4, the six-digit number $102564$ will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be the smallest number with such property. If it has $n+1$ digits, it can be represented as $N=10a+b$, where $a$ has $n$ digits and $1\leq b\leq 9$. Moving $b$ from the last to the first position, we obtain the number $M=10^n b+a$. From the condition $M=3N$ we obtain $10^n b+a = 3(10a+b)$, or $29a = (10^n - 3)b$. Hence, $29|(10^n - 3)b$; since $29$ is prime and $b\leq 9$, it follows that $29|10^n -3$, i.e., $10^n\equiv 3$ (mod $29$), whose smallest solution is $n=27$. Therefore,

$a=\frac{(10^{27}-3)}{29}b=34,482,758,620,689,655,172,413,793\, b$.

Since, by hypothesis, $a$ has $n\,(=27)$ digits, $b$ must be at least $3$ in the above equation; taking $b=3$ we obtain

$a=103,448,275,862,068,965,517,241,379$

and, finally,

$N=1,034,482,758,620,689,655,172,413,793$.